# App rejected due to violating iCloud storage guidelines

Tags: ios, core-data

My app was rejected recently due to the fact that it installs a database within a directory which will be backed up to iCloud. As the database comes with a lot of prepopulated data and the app stores user generated data into the same file.
So mixing up user-generated-content with prepopulated data is not was Apple wants us to do.
So far so good.

Separate my database into two and mark the store file with the prepopulated data with NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = YES.

But what happens if the user wants to modify the data in that store, because he found a failure and wish to modify it.
Or myself make an online update available which modifies values with that store.
How do I cope with that.

Do I have to delete the store file, create a new one (now with NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey = NO) or store the database under /tmp or /Library/caches right from the beginning and move it into /Application Support (which is backed up automatically) but with the threat that my database is being removed by the system for some reason what is the case for /Library/caches?

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit annoying that Apple will not allow you to backup prepopulated data if your app is of the kind where you could actually change the prepopulated data in the app. If the prepopulated database is big, I can however understand that they don't want your app to waste the user´s iCloud space with information that is already in the AppStore.

Woody has a good idea on the approach, but I'm not sure Apple would look away from the fact that you are actually wasting just as much space if you copy the prepopulated data to the user-backed-up DB on app startup.

What about something like this:

- **A:** DB with pre-populated data, not backed up
- **B:** DB with user added
  data, backed up
- When user make changes to object in A, crete a new row in B that "overrides" the row in A, for example by using the same ID or by having a column in the DB that tells the app which object in A should be replaced by the new row in B.

Whenever you need to update your app, you will replace DB A with new content and that's it. This could lead to conflicts with the data that the user has changed. You will have to decide whether the user data is more important than the updated data, and how to handle these conflicts (for example by trying to keep them both).

If you need to change the structure of DB B in an update, for example if you need to add a column, you will have to include an update routine in your app that detects that the user is having an old DB version and write code to migrate the user data to the new database on first startup after the update.

Comment: Thx. What your question about .. not sure Apple would look away .. is concerned - they wont! The solution you suggest leaves it open how I can decide which item to choose in a fetch request. Am I right that for your solution I'd had to spead an entity over to persistent stores. Can core data handle this? Do I had to route fetch requests for a certain item always to the "user-generated" store and if it fails route it the other store? Could core data do this automatically. Sorry for that bunch of new question but I'm realy looking for a future proof solution

Comment: Just import DB A in you app bundle and handle it as you would any DB when not using iCloud. I've done this several times and it is fairly easy, you should have no problems finding a guide for this. Make sure DB A is not committed to iCloud. As for the routing, simply show the data from both DBs in your app. (if you have a table with all content let its list be filled with all objects from both DBS) Whenever there is an "overriding" row in DB B, do not show the corresponding row from DB A. You will need to code this functionality yourself, it will not be handled automatically.

Comment: okay just for clarification. You **can** spread entities over two persistent stores. As the coordinator handles both stores there is no change in code for fetching objects (e.g. NSFetchedResultsController). The **only** thing I have to do is figuring out if it finds too items with the same whatsoever_id and decide which one newer. P.S. For the time being I'm not using iCloud services. Its just the backup - so no sync or so.

Answer (score 0):

When you startup, if the user database is unpopulated you could copy the data across from the pre-populated datatabse, and maybe give the user an option to reset defaults which does the same again?

Comment: Thx Woody. I've written something in my answer above.