# My app rejected Appstore due to iOS Data Storage Guidelines Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I developed an application and submitted to AppStore, but after few days it got rejected for violating "iCloud Data Storage Guideline".

I am only saving my "`CoreDataModel.sqlite`" database file in the Documents Directory. Apple is saying "We found that on launch and/or content download, your app stores 2.73MB on iCloud".

I find this one [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html) but i don't know how to use this please can any one help to me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: The answer is probably: don't pre-populate your database. See [App rejected due to violating iCloud storage guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222039/app-rejected-due-to-violating-icloud-storage-guidelines).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you download stuff you save it in a temp/cache folder and not back it up or store it in iCloud. You can manually exclude files from being backup up to iCloud. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26271909/why-my-app-is-rejected-from-appstore-although-i-am-not-using-icloud) has instructions on how to do so. 2.73MB for a DB file is much, make sure you are not saving images within the database but references to them.

Comment: Neither is 2.7MB too much for a Database, nor would it help to store images as references. They have to be stored either way. Excluding a database that contains user data from backup just to pass App Review is a horrible idea. The problem is most likely that the database is pre-populated. I have apps that have databases that are >100 MB, never had a problem because they start at zero and get bigger when the user adds data.

Comment: My answer is to exclude any file that can be redownloaded. In this case it happens to be a database. So I never said to exclude a database with user data.